# Some SQS messages never reaching Lambda, even though I received a Message ID from sendMessage

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm having a weird problem (that maybe is attributed to me just not understanding some of the intricacies of SQS) where I send 62 messages to a queue, receive valid `MessageId`s back from AWS but some of those messages (~5%) never actually make it to my Lambda.

My queuing code looks like this:

```
let data = await sqs.sendMessageBatch(params).promise();
console.log(`Queued ${data.Successful.length} records`);
if(data.Failed.length > 0){
   console.log(`ERROR not all messages were properly queued. `, data);
}
data.Successful.forEach(m => console.log(`MessageId=${m.MessageId}`));
```

In every case, every message is successful and this code prints out a `MessageId`.  Common scenario is that I'm sending batches of 10 records (the max `sendMessageBatch` allows) and an entire batch goes missing.  So, of 62 records, 10 are missing or 2 are missing.

The Lambda takes each of those messages and inserts a row into a database, so it's pretty easy to tell that messages are missing.  As far as I'm aware there is no way to look up an SQS message by its ID, so even though I have that ID, there's nothing I can do with it.

I have pretty extensive logging and looking through the logs I can tell no Lambda instance ever received those missing messages.  I can count all the other times the Lambda spun up and processed a record, but it's always 50 or 52 instead of 62 times.

Where are my messages going?

Comment: Did you check your queue?

Comment: yes, of course.

Comment: Did you check the metrics regarding how many messages sent? How many received etc?

Comment: Is your Lambda function logging the message IDs of all messages it receives?